# Sampling from conjugate Dirichlet distribution

Tags: bayesian, random-generation, dirichlet-distribution, conjugate-prior

[Conjugate prior for Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Conjugate_prior_of_the_Dirichlet_distribution), as described by Lefkimmiatis, Maragos, and Papandreou (2009; see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20399/conjugate-prior-of-the-dirichlet-distribution) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183383/dirichlet-conjugate-update-derivation)), has form

$$
f(\boldsymbol{\alpha}) \propto \frac{1}{B(\boldsymbol{\alpha})^\eta} 
\;e^{-\sum_k v_k \alpha_k}
$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Conjugate_prior_of_the_Dirichlet_distribution) notes that "there is no practical algorithm to efficiently generate samples" from it. Why is that?

> Lefkimmiatis, S., Maragos, P., & Papandreou, G. (2009). [Bayesian
>   inference on multiscale models for Poisson intensity estimation:
>   Applications to photon-limited image denoising.](http://cvsp.cs.ntua.gr/publications/jpubl+bchap/LefkimmiatisMaragosPapandreou_BayesianMultiscalePoissonIntensityEstimation_ieee-j-ip09.pdf) IEEE Transactions
>   on Image Processing, 18(8), 1724-1741. (Appendix C)

Comment: The difficulty comes from the $B(\mathbf{\alpha})$ function, which is intractable...